# Axios is not defined

Tags: laravel, axios

Estoy implementando axios en mi aplicación en `Laravel` tuve que hacerlo a mano la implementacion de `laravel mix` entre otras cosas.
**Package.js**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    ..
  },
```

Ya intente incluirlo en mi `app.js` y no me funciona

```
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(axios)
```

Alguien sabe porqueme sigue marcando error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined"
```

Componente

```
axios.get('api/bloques')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.warn(err)
            })
```

No se si me falte agregarlo en algún lado para usarlo de forma global.

Comment: Ya verificaste en tu carpeta de NODE_MODULES, si se encuentra el paquete de axios? (Si no lo encuentra, intenta correr el comando npm install

Comment: de echo si se encuentra en `node_modules`

Comment: alfin los pudistes solucionar?

Comment: Las devDependencies son las dependencias que necesitas en tiempo de desarrollo pero no sirven para nada concreto del proyecto (por ejemplo una librería que te indique si el código no sigue unas normas de estilo concretas), por lo tanto no se incluyen cuando se construye el proyecto. Si quieres que la librería "axios" te funcione al contruir el proyecto debería estar dentro de "dependencies" (y no "devDependencies")

Answer (score 1):

Intenta incluirlo en tu archivo, componente.js, es decir:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.get('api/bloques')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.warn(err)
            })
```

Comment: seria muy tedioso incluirlo de por componente

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo crear un servicio base para ayudarte en todas las tareas con axios, tal que:

```
// axios-base.js

import axios from 'axios'

const VueAxios = axios.create({
  // timeout: 10000,
  headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN': authToken}
})

const AxiosUtils = {
  vuex: null,
  errorNotifier: null
}

export default {
  getApiResource (url, params, options = {}) {
    return VueAxios.get(Routing.generate(url, params), options)
    // El Routing.generate(...) es un script de Symfony para utilizar su generador de rutas, tu puedes pasárle la url a cada uno de los métodos como quieras (la recibe como primer parámetro en .get, .post, ... etc)
  },
  postApiResource (url, params, body) {
    return VueAxios.post(...)
  },
  patchApiResource (url, params, body) {
    return VueAxios.patch...
  },
  deleteApiResource (url, params, body) {
   ...
  },
  setErrorNotifier (notifier) {
    AxiosUtils.errorNotifier = notifier
  }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto importas en App.vue (o tu fichero principal):

`import Api from 'turuta/axios-base.js'`

Si lo haces así lo tendrás mucho mas controlado, centralizado y podrás controlar cualquier excepción y/o interceptores desde aquí.

Si sigue sin irte d todas formas prueba a quitarlo de --save-dev y guardalo solo con --save.